# Jira questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I was surprised at the response to https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/14063/is-it-possible-to-create-a-jira-user-with-dl-email-and-subscribe-to-filters.  One commenter wrote, "'m voting to close this question as off-topic because, its about ALM tooling and not SQA or testing. Maybe ask on pm.stackexchange.com".

I know a lot of folks who use Jira as a bug-tracking tool.  Do we really want to avoid Jira questions here?

Answer (score 3):

The voting for offtopic is not because it's JIRA as an issue tracker but because it's an "programming" question about a software with user management. So it has nothing to do with SQA.

For example replace the word JIRA with lets say an online game. the question is still the same and not related to SQA.

I personally would have voted it to migrate to SuperUsers but I think it is in a grey mixed zone between SU and PM.

Comment: Except that JIRA is a tool used by testers and online games aren't...

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I've seen many teams where JIRA is only used for bug tracking, while other applications are used for the rest of the ALM solution.  Personally, I would expect the answer to be on either PM or SQA as I do see many testers needing to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think Jira is a project management tool with only limited QA functionality if any at all. Maybe with some plugins, but those are not so good either. Jira is to manage the SDLC. Question about Jira are there for a better fit for https://pm.stackexchange.com/

There is a [new question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17647/can-i-import-jira-tickets-into-redmine) only about JIRA and another tool Redmine. I do not see the relation to SQA. Also I think PM.SE has more experience with setting up Jira.

Comment: Can you describe the dividing line between project management tools and tools with QA functionality?  Lots of companies use Jira for bug tracking, which tells me you do not consider bug tracking to be QA functionality.

Comment: Bug tracking is more then just QA, it also end-user communication. As a user I have created a lot of bug reports in bugtrackers and monitored them. I see it again as a general tool of the SDLC, which is also used by QA. I am not sure Bugtrack KPI's are the sole ground of QA, although it can have a quality signaling function.

Comment: So your reasoning is that if a tool can be used for more than just QA, we should not discuss it in SQA.  (Similar to how we treat programming language questions.)

Comment: I guess, a bit similar to programming questions. If the programming is testing specific we answer them else we vote them off-topic. The same goes for Jira. If it is about testing-plugins, qa-metrics/dashboarding it could fit. If it just about Jira setup or project-management I think it is a better fit for PM.SE